# Why is @EnableScheduling not enabled by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

When scheduling tasks using the `@Scheduled` annotation in Spring, we also need to include `@EnableScheduling` in the main method where `@SpringBootApplication` is present.

Why is this not enabled by default? For example, why doesn't `@SpringBootApplication`, which by itself is already a [convenience annotation consisting multiple different annotations](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) just include `@EnableScheduling` as well? Is it because there's some side-effect of this annotation I am not aware of?

Comment: `@EnableScheduling` requires the existence of a `TaskScheduler` if you don't have it it will blow up. Which task scheduler to use is hard to determine. Next to that there is also `@EnableAsync` you could have an async scheduled method, then what. Not every application needs scheduling (or has access to multithreading).

Comment: @M.Deinum That should be an answer.